# Problems with static files django, IIS 10 and windows 10

Tags: python, django, iis, django-staticfiles

Problems with static files django, IIS and windows 10

Hi I have Python 3.10.4, Django 4.0.4 and wfastcgi 3.0.0 installed. This on windows server 2016 and the latest version of IIS as of 05/20/2022. I have already run the command manage.py runserver collectstatic. Does not show static files when viewing the web application on the internet.

This file is web.config which is outside the project folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="Python FastCGI"
        path="*" 
        verb="*"
        modules="FastCgiModule" 
        scriptProcessor="C:\Python35\python.exe|C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" 
        resourceType="Unspecified" />

      <add name="Proyectoqr" 
        path="*" 
        verb="*" 
        modules="FastCgiModule"
        scriptProcessor="C:\Python35\python.exe|C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" 
        resourceType="Unspecified" 
        requireAccess="Script" />
      
      <add name="PythonHandler" 
        path="*" 
        verb="*" 
        modules="FastCgiModule" 
        scriptProcessor="C:\Python35\python.exe|C:\Python35\lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" 
        resourceType="Unspecified"
        requireAccess="Script" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="PYTHONPATH" value="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\proyectoqr" />
    <add key="WSGI_HANDLER" value="proyectoqr.wsgi.application" />
    <add key="DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE" value="proyectoqr.settings" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

This is the content of the web.config file in the static folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="StaticFile" path="*" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I already added the virtual directory of the static folder with direction to the static folder of the project as shown in the following image.

[image]

If you need more information tell me to show you the code or configuration

Achieve settings.py

```
import os
from pathlib import Path
from telnetlib import LOGOUT
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-qqhlm_^kgh#ri8^c_5)3_-vn@w(b_2t&v%!2o*d(xli6%&-pgg'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['10.100.10.133', 'localhost', "127.0.0.1:8000", '127.0.0.1']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    
    'import_export',

    "apps.equipo",
    "apps.usuariof",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'proyectoqr.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ["templates"],
        
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'proyectoqr.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-mx'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = ''

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
#STATICFILES_DIRS = (BASE_DIR,'static')
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGOUT_URL = 'logout'
```

[image]

This is how I create the url's in python

```
                    <li class="menu-item-has-children dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> <i class="menu-icon fa fa-book"></i>Historial de prestamos</a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu children dropdown-menu">                           
                             <li><i class="fa fa-table"></i><a href="{% url 'equipo:listar_prestamos' %}">Listado de prestamos</a></li>                    
                             <li><i class="fa fa-table"></i><a href="{% url 'equipo:listar_prestamos_no_devueltos' %}">Listado de prestamos en curso</a></li>
                             <li><i class="fa fa-table"></i><a href="{% url 'equipo:listar_prestamos_devueltos' %}">Listado de prestamos terminados</a></li>
                         </ul>
 
                     </li>
```

This is my urls.py file which is located in the project folder

```
from django.contrib import admin
#from django.conf.urls import url
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.contrib.auth import login, logout
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView, logout_then_login
from apps.equipo.views import home, Inicio
from apps.usuariof.views import Login, logoutUsuario

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path("equipo/", include(("apps.equipo.urls","equipo"))),
    path("index", login_required(Inicio.as_view()), name="index"),
    path("test", Inicio.as_view(), name="test"),
    path('accounts/login/', Login.as_view(), name='login'),
    path("logout/", login_required(logoutUsuario), name="logout")
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Comment: is `settings.STATIC_URL` correct?

Comment: I just attached the settings.py file if you need to see another file let me know and thanks for the help

Comment: STATIC_URL is defined twice, and the last one is `STATIC_URL = '/static/'`. Does your webserver answer on `https://<your-dns>/static/`? Are the links generated by the `{% static ".." %}` tag going to urls that start with `https://<your-dns>/static/...`?

Comment: thanks for the help but now I'm not at work I'll implement your solution on Monday I'll tell you the result

Comment: Does it work fine locally? or is this problem only on iis?

Comment: Sorry for not answering I was very busy with other things at work.
The error is not fixed yet, when using a server with static it does not show anything and marks error 500.
I attach a new code of how I create the url's.

Comment: HTTP Error 500.19 - Error 0x8007000d says about invalid element in your web.config. That's why IIS cannnot read this file for start your site. You can find probloem element by commenting some blocks and looking for type of error.

Comment: Change FastCGI attributes but I couldn't fix the problem

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem based on your description, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.